# Need Root For Asus Zenfone 5(T00J) 8 GB(Kitkat ROM)

Tags: rooting, asus-zenfone-5

I Need to root my Zenfone 5 (Asus T00J) - 8 GB Kitkat ROM, But I can't find any solution over Internet. Please help me to get the root for Asus Zenfone 5.  Also need The CWM.

Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

**For Android 4.4.2**
I've tried solution [here](https://androidmtk.com/root-asus-zenfone-5) with success. Just need to run bat file to root or unroot.
[image]

Notes:

1. Need windows pc
2. Needs to rename "recovery-ww.img" to "recovery-root.img" (look
   comment section of link given above)
3. Only for android version 4.4.2